# Repo Init Fatal: error unknown url type

Tags: android, repository

I am using repo to sync my local android source code. I have followed the instructions on the android source website: http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html

When I try to do repo init:

```
repo init -u http://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest
```

I get the following error:

```
fatal: Cannot get http://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo/clone.bundle
fatal: error unknown url type: https
```

I have followed multiple threads on google and have modified my repo scripts and changed the https to http in the REPO_URL but I am continuing to get the same error.

What else do I need to do?

Please help.

Markus

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have answered my own question.

Since I last did a repo sync I had cleared my HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY variables.

```
export HTTP_PROXY=http://<proxy_user_id>:<proxy_password>@<proxy_server>:<proxy_port>
export HTTPS_PROXY=http://<proxy_user_id>:<proxy_password>@<proxy_server>:<proxy_port>
```

Running this for my company settings fixed the problem.

Markus